# Problems with TouchListView and Drag and Drop (commonsware)

Tags: android, listview, commonsware-cwac

CommonsWare, I got some problems with your Touchlist. Starting the Demo in a sperate project isnt any problem. But when i try to import the files in my exsisting project, in the xml file where i declare your TouchListView it says this:

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'normal_height' in package 'it.sec'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'expanded_height' in package 
     'it.sec'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'grabber' in package 'it.sec'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'remove_mode' in package 'it.sec'

Does anybody got an idea what ive to do?
Thanks in advance

sMau

Comment: Please post your layout file containing these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you will create a custom layout use something like this (and don't forget to change "YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE_NAME" to you real package name :-)

```
<com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.TouchListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tlv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE_NAME"

    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    tlv:normal_height="64dip"
    tlv:grabber="@+id/icon"
    tlv:remove_mode="slideRight"
/>
```