# Problems with TouchListView and Drag and Drop?

Tags: android, listview, commonsware-cwac

I created an application this application contain listview , and I want to remove items one by one by sliding to right or left , and here my code :

```
<com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.TouchListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tlv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.listviewremoveitem"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    tlv:grabber="@+id/icon"
    tlv:normal_height="64dip"
    tlv:remove_mode="slideRight" />
```

and I got this error :

`Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'grabber' in package 
     'com.listviewremoveitem'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'remove_mode' in package 
     'com.listviewremoveitem'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'normal_height' in package 
     'com.listviewremoveitem'

and I found something it's too similar with my error 
[Problems with TouchListView and Drag and Drop (commonsware)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417400/problems-with-touchlistview-and-drag-and-drop-commonsware) 
but the answer didn't helpful , and this is my package [ `package="com.listviewremoveitem"` ] .

Does anybody got an idea what I've to do?

Comment: As Krylez notes in his answer, `TouchListView` has been discontinued for about two years. I strongly encourage you to use some other component.

Comment: ok what's the other component? like what ? please send to me any link 
thanks you're right

Comment: I do not know of any currently-maintained alternative, though Krylez points to a video for one in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to include the file that declares those attributes. For class you're using, this is the `cwac_touchlist_attrs.xml` file.

Keep in mind that `TouchListView` is deprecated and no longer maintained. Here's a good alternative:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q

Comment: include cwac_touchlist_attrs.xml to where ?

Comment: It goes in your `res/values/` folder.

Comment: Thank you you're right , and still am stuck at this error , ok I will never use Touchlistview and thank you for your link :)